# Queue in Semaphores - even possible?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, message-queue, semaphore, vxworks

I have following C problem:
I have a hardware module that controls the SPI bus (as a master), let's call it **SPI_control**, it's got private (`static`) read & write and "public" `Init()` and `WriteRead()` functions (for those who don't know, SPI is full duplex i.e. a Write always reads data on the bus). Now I need to make this accessible to higher levekl modules that incorporate certain protocols. Let's cal the upper modules **TDM** and **AC**. They run in two separate threads and one might not be interrupted by the other (when it's in the nmiddle of a transaction, it first needs to complete).

So one possibility I thought of, is to incorporate a **SPI_ENG** inbween the modules and the **SPI_control** which controls data flow and know what can be interrupted and what can't - it would then forward data accordingly to **spi_control**. But hwo can the independent tasks **AC & **TDM** talk to **spi_control**, can I have them to write to and read from some kind ok Semaphore queue? How is should this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but a general solution is that your two processes (AC and TDM) can write data in their own separate output queues. A third process can act as a scheduler and read alternatively from these queue and write on to the HW (SPI_control). This may be what you are looking for since the queues will also act as elasticity buffers to handle bursty transactions.
This ways you will not have to worry about AC getting preempted TDM, there should be no need for Mutex's to synchronize the accesses to SPI_Control.

Queues in kernel are implemented using kernel semaphores. A Queue is an array of memory guarded by an kernel semaphore.

What I would do is create a control msg queue for the Scheduler tasks. So now system will have 3 queue. 2 data output queues for AC, TDM process and one Control queue for Scheduler task. During system startup scheduler task will start before AC and TDM and pend on its control queue. The AC and TDM process should send "data available" msg to scheduler task over the control queue whenever their queue goes non empty (msgQNumMsgs()). On receiving this msg, the scheduler task should start reading from the specific queue until it is empty and again pend on the control queue. The last time I worked on vxworks(2004), it had a flat memory model, in which all the global variables were accessible to all tasks. Is it this the case? If yes then you can use global variable to pass queue Id's between tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a Mutex on each SPI operation:

```
SPI_Read()
{
    MutexGet(&spiMutex);
    ...
    MutexPut(&spiMutex);
}


SPI_Write()
{
    MutexGet(&spiMutex);
    ...
    MutexPut(&spiMutex);
}
```

Make sure that you initialize the Mutex with priority-inheritance enabled, so that it can perform priority-inversion whenever needed.

Comment: Where does the mutex (and its priority-inversion capabilities) come from?

Comment: @barak manos Thanks but this won't take care of the transactions in the protocols that must not be interrupted to allow for graceful transfer completion.

Comment: Why not? Any thread trying to access the SPI will be blocked by the mutex, until the current thread which owns the mutex has completed.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: A mutex is an OS resource. In the case above, a VxWorks OS resource. It should come along with the OS (any OS) library.

Comment: @barak manos Yes, fine but Read & Write may need to happen in one piece, thus I came up with that `WriteRead()` function, a **write** always does a **read**. I guess I need to do some reading about "priority-inversion" and how to initialize a mutex with it enabled, do you have links or examples handy?

Comment: I do, but only in ThreadX OS. With regards to the ReadWrite happening in one piece, just acquire a Mutex at the beginning of the function, and release it at the end, exactly as described in the answer above.